# Run same coroutine periodically with aiohttp and aiojobs

Tags: python, aiohttp

I have a manager to cache some user settings. I want to cleanup it  every hour for inactive users (10 seconds in my example). I try to use aiojobs for this. I spawn the same job inside the job coroutine.

```
from aiohttp import web
from aiojobs.aiohttp import setup, get_scheduler
import asyncio

async def cleanup(scheduler):
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print('do cleanup')
    await scheduler.spawn(cleanup(scheduler))

async def handler(request):
    if not request.app['init']:
        scheduler = get_scheduler(request)
        await scheduler.spawn(cleanup(scheduler))
        request.app['init'] = True
    return web.Response(text = 'ok')

def main():
    app = web.Application()
    app.router.add_get('/', handler)
    setup(app)
    app['init'] = False

    web.run_app(app, host='127.0.0.1', port = 8000)

main()
```

Is it a good solution? Should I create my own scheduler because my job does not relate to a request?

Answer (score 1):

I want some background tasks to run in the same loop as the aiohttp web server, even before any http requests arrive. It looks like aiojobs doesn't help me so I'm using something that looks like this. I'm using a janus queue because my real application makes blocking calls from another thread. I don't know aiosync well, so this may be the blind leading the blind.

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import web
from aiojobs.aiohttp import setup
import janus


async def ticket_maker(q: janus.Queue):
    counter = 1
    while True:
        print(f'Made ticket {counter}')
        await q.async_q.put(counter)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        counter += 1


async def handler(request):
    q: janus.Queue = request.app.get('Q')
    ticket = await q.async_q.get()
    return web.Response(text=f'You got ticket {ticket}')


def main():
    q = janus.Queue()

    app = web.Application()
    asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(ticket_maker(q))
    app.router.add_get('/', handler)
    app['Q'] = q
    setup(app)
    web.run_app(app, port=8080)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```